# c programming language : the app wont stop after typing x

Tags: c, break

i made this program and its working just how i want but it should stop when i type x but it doesn't 
can any one tell me why?
and if there is any shortcut or smaller way to type this code?
thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int meat[6];
    int i;
    int total =0;
    int avg;
    char what[20];
    char end;
    int days = 0;
    char food[20];
    char drink[20];
    printf("what thing do u want to calculate the average of?(food/drink)\n");
    scanf(" %s", &what);
    if(strcmp(what, "food")==0)
    {
        printf("what sort of food did u ate ?\n");
        scanf(" %s", food);
    }
    if(strcmp(what, "drink")==0)
    {
        printf("what sort of drink did u drank ?\n");
        scanf(" %s", drink);
    }
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)        
    {
        days++;
        if(strcmp(what, "food")==0) 
        {
            printf("how many %s did u ate in day %d\n", food, i+1);
        }
        else if(strcmp(what, "drink")==0)
        {
            printf("how many liters of %s did u drank in day %d\n", drink, i+1);
        }
        scanf(" %d", &meat[i]);
        total += meat[i];
        printf("if u want to continue type y\n");

        printf("type x if u want to finish\n");
        scanf(" %c", &end);
        if((end = 'y')&&(i<5))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(end = 'x' && strcmp(what, "drink")==0)
        {
            avg = total / days;
            printf("\nyour average amount of liters of %s you had %d\t the total is %d\n", drink, avg, total);
        }
        else if(end = 'x' && strcmp(what, "food")==0)
        {
            avg = total / days;
            printf("\nyour average amount of %s you had %d\t the total is %d\n", food, avg, total);
        }
        break;
    }
    if(strcmp(what, food)==0)
    {        
        printf("\nyour average amount of %s you had is %d\t the total is %d\n", food, avg, total);
    }
    else if(strcmp(what, drink)==0)
    {        
        printf("\nyour average amount of liters of %s you had is %d\t the total is %d\n", drink, avg, total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(end = 'x' ...
```

should be:

```
else if(end == 'x' ...
```

You use `==` to test equality in if statements. You've got this in a couple places in your code, which is inadvertently performing an assignment, not what you want to achieve by comparing if user input is equal to a particular character.

Replace the `=` with `==` here:

```
else if(end = 'x' && strcmp(what, "drink")==0)
```

here:

```
else if(end = 'x' && strcmp(what, "food")==0)
```

and here:

```
if((end = 'y')&&(i<5))
```

Comment: Two of those, also `if((end = 'y') ...)`

Comment: The x worked but now when entering the 6 days amount it doesnt cacoluate the avg or the total

Comment: I suspect you also have a logic error on your final comparison here `if(strcmp(what, food)==0)` and here `else if(strcmp(what, drink)==0)` as this expects the user to have typed in `food` or `drink`, as well as `food` or `drink` for what they ate, which doesn't appear to be what you asked the user to type. My guess is, you want to turn `food` and `drink` on those comparisons to `"food"` and `"drink"` respectively.

Comment: I have turned them and the same error not haveng avg and total after typing y for the 6th time

Comment: @talalalsharaa I compiled and ran your code, and I had no problem getting the calculation to print out after entering data on all 6 days. Couple things though: Your average is being declared as an `int`, but most often, averages are represented by `float` or `double`. You'll lose the precision if you don't change the data type and cast your total/days to the same data type. Secondly, if you type `y` a 6th time, your loop will terminate because there's no logic that says the calculation should be performed after the user has passed the 6th day. Currently, only `x` will force the calculation.